# htaccess - inserting request uri in errordocument url

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, errordocument

I've been searching and reading but not finding the answer.
So, I'm not really well-known with the working of .htaccess parameters.

### What I want to get working is this:

When my .htaccess errordocument gets triggered, the site redirects to /?p=error&e=404

This is basically a PHP page, which deals with the Get value of e, being the error code.

What I want is to add another Get key (hp) which has the request URI as value.

So, if I go to www.mysite.com/bla, the handling should be:

ErrorDocument 404 /?p=error&e=404&hp=bla

---

Only thing I can't seem to get done is to find and actually use the necessary variable for this.

Please help me out here..

Comment: You don't really need a parameter for this. Just `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` inside your PHP code to get the URI of page causing 404

Comment: Kay, this is where I feel silly.. I knew that, but didn't stop to think this way :p Thanks for your help!